# htaccess exclude a sub/subdirectory from a 302 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, server

I'm trying to exclude a directory that's 1 level deeper than one that already has a redirect.

So Redirect /department/team/
but exclude /department/team/employee/

I've already tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/department/team/employee/
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/department/team/employee/ - [L]
```

Here's current htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    $1  [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]

##RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/department/team/employee/

RewriteRule ^/department/team/employee/ - [L]
Redirect 302 /department/team/ https://example.com
```

Comment: You can not prevent the `Redirect` directive from doing its work by preceding it a RewriteRule that doesn’t rewrite and say [L]ast, those directives do not work together in combination like that, their behavior is independent of each other. You need to do the redirect via a RewriteRule as well here.

Comment: Plus, `Redirect` does prefix-based matching, and adds any excess part behind what was matched, to the new target URL. So if you match on `/department/team/` with that directive, that applies to `/department/team/…` as well.

Comment: So it's not possible as configured or do I need to do a rewrite rule on both?  Or should I find another method?

Comment: If you just want to rewrite that one particular URL, then use `RewriteRule ^department/team/$ new-url [R=302]`